# Slow function execution from google iot core MQTT modifyCloudToDeviceConfig()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iot

I am using google iot core with google cloud functions.
When I try update iot device config remotely with modifyCloudToDeviceConfig() function, I get an update in the device after 5-10 sec.

I run in firestorm cloud function onUpdate(). To execute cloud function it takes less than 100ms, but to finish MQTT request `devices.modifyCloudToDeviceConfig()` it takes at least 5 sec.
But when I use google iot core console to send a command to the device via 'Update Config', device will get this update immediately.

What can be the reason of slow modifyCloudToDeviceConfig() function execution?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue anymore `devices.modifyCloudToDeviceConfig()` is executing instantly within google cloud function.

When I executed within Firebase cloud function `onUpdate()` handler, to execute `modifyCloudToDeviceConfig()` would take over 5sec.

Comment: I'm having this problem with Dialogflow. Everytime I try to execute it takes between 5-15 seconds to get on iot.